# Java - GUI clock using large amounts of RAM?

Tags: java, timer

I made a little clock for a desktop widget in Java(the widget includes many other features as well). I checked the applications RAM usage in task manager to see that the clock was using 700+ MB of RAM. I disabled the clock and the RAM usage went down to about 60 MB. Here is the clocks code:

```
final int timeRun = 0;
    new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(timeRun == 0)
            {
                Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                int AM_PM = cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

                String day_night = "";

                if (AM_PM == 1){
                    day_night = "PM";
                }else{
                    day_night = "AM";
                }

                String time = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + day_night;
                Clock.setText(time);
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Why is it using so much RAM? How could I fix it?

Comment: you are constantly creating instances, although GC should be collecting it, but you don't really need to create new Calendar each iteration

Comment: Your loop/thread should wait for 1000ms if you are measuring seconds..

Comment: You're creating a large amount of short lived objects, as fast as the CPU can make them...since you're only updating the seconds, try putting a `Thread.sleep(500)` after the display...and are you displaying this on a GUI?  Cause you're violating the single thread rules of most UIs...

Comment: What GUI framework?  Swing/AWT/SWT/JavaFX/Android/...?

Comment: Maybe your RAM doesn't like String concatenation (and the new Calender) in each iteration and since your program uses an infinite loop without any chance for a "break" (no sleep, no wait, no yield), the Garbage Collector has a hard time to do his job.

Comment: @Tom +1 for `String` concatenation within a loop!

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's a swing UI and yes "Clock" is a jLabel.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The result will be pretty similar with any GUI framework. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Tom How could I avoid the String concatenation?

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan AWT is more thread safe then the others...but the mechanism you would use to solve it is different...

Comment: @Arman Create the variable `final String format = "%d:%d:%d %s";` (before you create the thread) and change `time` to `String time = String.format(format, hour, min, sec, day_night);`. But you might test the performane for both, since the compiler optimizes some stuff.

Comment: @MadProgrammer So you are saying this piece of code works "better" with AWT than , lets say Swing ?

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan I'm saying that there are less thread synchornisation issues, the code is still a bottleneck of carnage...mind you, I've not done any AWT based coding for more the 15 years, so I could be a little rusty on the concepts...

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's ok, I understood what you tried to mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Reduce the number of updates to the required minimum
2. Reduce the number of temporary objects as best as you can
3. Ensure that all updates to the UI are made from within the context of the main UI thread (Event Dispatching Thread for Swing)

Take a look at:

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

For example...

[image: Clock]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ClockMeBaby {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClockMeBaby();
    }

    public ClockMeBaby() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        protected static final DateFormat CLOCK_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
        private JLabel clock;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            clock = new JLabel("...");
            clock.setFont(clock.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 64f));
            add(clock);
            updateClock();

            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    updateClock();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        protected void updateClock() {

            clock.setText(CLOCK_FORMAT.format(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        }

    }

}
```

The reason the `SwingTimer` uses a `500` millisecond delay is to ensure we remain in sync, otherwise your clock might update "out of sync" with the rest of the UI because you've missed a second boundry.  If this is not important to you, you could us `1000` millisecond delay instead

Comment: Nice answer. +1 for getting rid of Calendar and all the other useless initializations, and for giving an improved solution! (and the animated gif..)