# Repaint method doesn't work or loop

Tags: java, while-loop, paint, repaint

**I don't know if I'm using the method repaint corretly, i need to update the time of a digital clock, but even with a while loop trying to repaint, it doesn't work**

```
public class Frame extends JFrame{


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int[] horaD = new int[14];
    int[] horaU = new int[14];
    int[] minD = new int[14];
    int[] minU = new int[14];
    int[] segD = new int[14];
    int[] segU = new int[14];

    public Frame(){
        this.setTitle("Relógio Digital");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setSize(1000, 400);
        this.setVisible(true); 
    }

    public void obterHora(){
        verificaHora();
        verificaMinuto();
        verificaSegundo();
    }

    public void verificaHora(){

        int d;
        int u;
        int i = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        char[] digitos = String.valueOf(i).toCharArray();
        if(digitos.length == 2){
            d = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(digitos[0]));
            u = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(digitos[1]));
        }else{
            d = 0;
            u = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(digitos[0]));
        }

        switch(d){
            case 0:
                horaD = Numeros.Zero;
                break;
            case 1:
                horaD = Numeros.Um;
                break;
            case 2:
                horaD = Numeros.Dois;
                break;
            default:
                horaU = Numeros.Zero;
                break;
        }

        switch(u){
            case 0:
                horaU = Numeros.Zero;
                break;
            case 1:
                horaU = Numeros.Um;
                break;
            case 2:
                horaU = Numeros.Dois;
                break;
            case 3:
                horaU = Numeros.Tres;
                break;
            case 4:
                horaU = Numeros.Quatro;
                break;
            case 5:
                horaU = Numeros.Cinco;
                break;
            case 6:
                horaU = Numeros.Seis;
                break;
            case 7:
                horaU = Numeros.Sete;
                break;
            case 8:
                horaU = Numeros.Oito;
                break;
            case 9:
                horaU = Numeros.Nove;
                break;
            default:
                horaU = Numeros.Zero;
                break;
        }   
    }   
    public void verificaMinuto(){

        int d;
        int u;
        int i = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        char[] digitos = String.valueOf(i).toCharArray();
        if(digitos.length == 2){
            d = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(digitos[0]));
            u = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(digitos[1]));
        }else{
            d = 0;
            u = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(digitos[0]));
        }
        switch(d){
            case 0:
                minD = Numeros.Zero;
                break;
            case 1:
                minD = Numeros.Um;
                break;
            case 2:
                minD = Numeros.Dois;
                break;
            case 3:
                minD = Numeros.Tres;
                break;
            case 4:
                minD = Numeros.Quatro;
                break;
            case 5:
                minD = Numeros.Cinco;
                break;
            default:
                minD = Numeros.Zero;
                break;
        }

        switch(u){
            case 0:
                minU = Numeros.Zero;
                break;
            case 1:
                minU = Numeros.Um;
                break;
            case 2:
                minU = Numeros.Dois;
                break;
            case 3:
                minU = Numeros.Tres;
                break;
            case 4:
                minU = Numeros.Quatro;
                break;
            case 5:
                minU = Numeros.Cinco;
                break;
            case 6:
                minU = Numeros.Seis;
                break;
            case 7:
                minU = Numeros.Sete;
                break;
            case 8:
                minU = Numeros.Oito;
                break;
            case 9:
                minU = Numeros.Nove;
                break;
            default:
                minU = Numeros.Zero;
                break;
        }   
    }
    public void verificaSegundo(){

        int d;
        int u;
        int i = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        char[] digitos = String.valueOf(i).toCharArray();
        if(digitos.length == 2){
            d = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(digitos[0]));
            u = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(digitos[1]));
        }else{
            d = 0;
            u = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(digitos[0]));
        }

        switch(d){
            case 0:
                segD = Numeros.Zero;
                break;
            case 1:
                segD = Numeros.Um;
                break;
            case 2:
                segD = Numeros.Dois;
                break;
            case 3:
                segD = Numeros.Tres;
                break;
            case 4:
                segD = Numeros.Quatro;
                break;
            case 5:
                segD = Numeros.Cinco;
                break;
            default:
                segD = Numeros.Zero;
                break;
        }

        switch(u){
            case 0:
                segU = Numeros.Zero;
                break;
            case 1:
                segU = Numeros.Um;
                break;
            case 2:
                segU = Numeros.Dois;
                break;
            case 3:
                segU = Numeros.Tres;
                break;
            case 4:
                segU = Numeros.Quatro;
                break;
            case 5:
                segU = Numeros.Cinco;
                break;
            case 6:
                segU = Numeros.Seis;
                break;
            case 7:
                segU = Numeros.Sete;
                break;
            case 8:
                segU = Numeros.Oito;
                break;
            case 9:
                segU = Numeros.Nove;
                break;
            default:
                segU = Numeros.Zero;
                break;
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){

        g.setColor(Color.black);

        obterHora();

        //Dígito da dezena da hora
        g.fillRect(100, 100, horaD[0], horaD[7]);
        g.fillRect(100, 100, horaD[1], horaD[8]);
        g.fillRect(200, 100, horaD[2], horaD[9]);
        g.fillRect(100, 200, horaD[3], horaD[10]);
        g.fillRect(200, 200, horaD[4], horaD[11]);
        g.fillRect(100, 200, horaD[5], horaD[12]);
        g.fillRect(100, 300, horaD[6], horaD[13]);

        //Dígito da unidade da hora
        g.fillRect(230, 100, horaU[0], horaU[7]);
        g.fillRect(230, 100, horaU[1], horaU[8]);
        g.fillRect(330, 100, horaU[2], horaU[9]);
        g.fillRect(230, 200, horaU[3], horaU[10]);
        g.fillRect(330, 200, horaU[4], horaU[11]);
        g.fillRect(230, 200, horaU[5], horaU[12]);
        g.fillRect(230, 300, horaU[6], horaU[13]);

        //Dois pontos (Hora/Minuto)
        g.fillRect(365, 180, 15, 15);
        g.fillRect(365, 215, 15, 15);

        //Dígito da dezena do minuto
        g.fillRect(400, 100, minD[0], minD[7]);
        g.fillRect(400, 100, minD[1], minD[8]);
        g.fillRect(500, 100, minD[2], minD[9]);
        g.fillRect(400, 200, minD[3], minD[10]);
        g.fillRect(500, 200, minD[4], minD[11]);
        g.fillRect(400, 200, minD[5], minD[12]);
        g.fillRect(400, 300, minD[6], minD[13]);

        //Dígito da unidade do minuto
        g.fillRect(530, 100, minU[0], minU[7]);
        g.fillRect(530, 100, minU[1], minU[8]);
        g.fillRect(630, 100, minU[2], minU[9]);
        g.fillRect(530, 200, minU[3], minU[10]);
        g.fillRect(630, 200, minU[4], minU[11]);
        g.fillRect(530, 200, minU[5], minU[12]);
        g.fillRect(530, 300, minU[6], minU[13]);

        //Dois pontos (Minuto/Segundo)
        g.fillRect(665, 180, 15, 15);
        g.fillRect(665, 215, 15, 15);

        //Dígito da dezena do segundo
        g.fillRect(700, 100, segD[0], segD[7]);
        g.fillRect(700, 100, segD[1], segD[8]);
        g.fillRect(800, 100, segD[2], segD[9]);
        g.fillRect(700, 200, segD[3], segD[10]);
        g.fillRect(800, 200, segD[4], segD[11]);
        g.fillRect(700, 200, segD[5], segD[12]);
        g.fillRect(700, 300, segD[6], segD[13]);

        //Dígito da unidade do segundo
        g.fillRect(830, 100, segU[0], segU[7]);
        g.fillRect(830, 100, segU[1], segU[8]);
        g.fillRect(930, 100, segU[2], segU[9]);
        g.fillRect(830, 200, segU[3], segU[10]);
        g.fillRect(930, 200, segU[4], segU[11]);
        g.fillRect(830, 200, segU[5], segU[12]);
        g.fillRect(830, 300, segU[6], segU[13]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Frame f = new Frame();
        while(true){
            f.repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

**I improved my code, but I have to delay the repaint every second using a Thread, because my teacher didn't want me to use Timer for this code, I tried this but it still doesn't update**

```
public class Frame extends JFrame{
HoraExata he = new HoraExata(); //Exact Time

private int[] horaD = new int[14];
private int[] horaU = new int[14];
private int[] minD = new int[14];
private int[] minU = new int[14];
private int[] segD = new int[14];
private int[] segU = new int[14];

public Frame(){
    this.setTitle("Relógio Digital");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    this.setSize(1000, 400);
}

 public void atualizaHora() { //Update Time
     while (true) {
             repaint();
             try {
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             }
     }
 }

public void obterHora(){ //Get the values to make each number in canvas
    horaD = he.verificaHora(1);
    horaU = he.verificaHora(2);
    minD = he.verificaMinuto(1);
    minU = he.verificaMinuto(2);
    segD = he.verificaSegundo(1);
    segU = he.verificaSegundo(2);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    g.setColor(Color.black);

    obterHora();

    //Dígito da dezena da hora
    g.fillRect(100, 100, horaD[0], horaD[7]);
    g.fillRect(100, 100, horaD[1], horaD[8]);
    g.fillRect(200, 100, horaD[2], horaD[9]);
    g.fillRect(100, 200, horaD[3], horaD[10]);
    g.fillRect(200, 200, horaD[4], horaD[11]);
    g.fillRect(100, 200, horaD[5], horaD[12]);
    g.fillRect(100, 300, horaD[6], horaD[13]);

    //Dígito da unidade da hora
    g.fillRect(230, 100, horaU[0], horaU[7]);
    g.fillRect(230, 100, horaU[1], horaU[8]);
    g.fillRect(330, 100, horaU[2], horaU[9]);
    g.fillRect(230, 200, horaU[3], horaU[10]);
    g.fillRect(330, 200, horaU[4], horaU[11]);
    g.fillRect(230, 200, horaU[5], horaU[12]);
    g.fillRect(230, 300, horaU[6], horaU[13]);

    //Dois pontos (Hora/Minuto)
    g.fillRect(365, 180, 15, 15);
    g.fillRect(365, 215, 15, 15);

    //Dígito da dezena do minuto
    g.fillRect(400, 100, minD[0], minD[7]);
    g.fillRect(400, 100, minD[1], minD[8]);
    g.fillRect(500, 100, minD[2], minD[9]);
    g.fillRect(400, 200, minD[3], minD[10]);
    g.fillRect(500, 200, minD[4], minD[11]);
    g.fillRect(400, 200, minD[5], minD[12]);
    g.fillRect(400, 300, minD[6], minD[13]);

    //Dígito da unidade do minuto
    g.fillRect(530, 100, minU[0], minU[7]);
    g.fillRect(530, 100, minU[1], minU[8]);
    g.fillRect(630, 100, minU[2], minU[9]);
    g.fillRect(530, 200, minU[3], minU[10]);
    g.fillRect(630, 200, minU[4], minU[11]);
    g.fillRect(530, 200, minU[5], minU[12]);
    g.fillRect(530, 300, minU[6], minU[13]);

    //Dois pontos (Minuto/Segundo)
    g.fillRect(665, 180, 15, 15);
    g.fillRect(665, 215, 15, 15);

    //Dígito da dezena do segundo
    g.fillRect(700, 100, segD[0], segD[7]);
    g.fillRect(700, 100, segD[1], segD[8]);
    g.fillRect(800, 100, segD[2], segD[9]);
    g.fillRect(700, 200, segD[3], segD[10]);
    g.fillRect(800, 200, segD[4], segD[11]);
    g.fillRect(700, 200, segD[5], segD[12]);
    g.fillRect(700, 300, segD[6], segD[13]);

    //Dígito da unidade do segundo
    g.fillRect(830, 100, segU[0], segU[7]);
    g.fillRect(830, 100, segU[1], segU[8]);
    g.fillRect(930, 100, segU[2], segU[9]);
    g.fillRect(830, 200, segU[3], segU[10]);
    g.fillRect(930, 200, segU[4], segU[11]);
    g.fillRect(830, 200, segU[5], segU[12]);
    g.fillRect(830, 300, segU[6], segU[13]);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Frame f = new Frame();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.atualizaHora();
}
```

}

Comment: the method you seek is `paintComponent`

Comment: Why do you need a `while-loop` to keep calling `repaint`?

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, calling repaint method does not necessarily mean that the UI is going to be painted again. It is controlled by JVM whether the UI is going to be painted again or not. This basically is a built-in feature in JAVA. If the JVM detects that the UI has changed then only the JVM will again paint the UI. Here calling the `repaint` method only only triggers the JVM to see whether the UI requires to be painted again. Like minimizing restoring and maximzing the frame will result to repaint being called without any code being used.

Here also note that you have overridden the `paint` method of the `JFrame`. You should override the `paintComponent` method and there should be a line at the begining

```
super.paintComponent();
```

This ensures that the `JFrame`'s default painting method is complete so that when you make changes by painting different shapes, it can be reflected on the already drawn `JFrame`.

Also for showing the `JFrame` from your `main` method you should use:

```
Frame f = new Frame();
f.setVisible(true);
```

In order to make the frame visible.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing fundamentally wrong on a number of levels

It looks like you're trying to generate a "clock" of some kind, I presume you're trying to paint a "segment" clock, but I'll need to keep digging.

- Don't extend `JFrame`, it's a fundamentally bad place to start, lots of reasons for this; you lock yourself into a single use case, `JFrame`'s have a `JRootPane` and `contentPane` which can be painted without requiring the frame to be painted first ...
- Don't override `paint`, generally, doing so can cause no end of issues and is generally discouraged, it's generally preferable to use a `JPanel` or `JComponent` and extend override its `paintComponent` method.  Paint is complex and you need to be careful what you do, have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details
- You should be calling the `paint` methods `super` method to ensure that you don't screw up the painting process
- A `while-loop` is a poor choice for trying to update the UI, instead I'd suggest using a Swing `Timer` instead, see [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details. The `Timer` reports ticks within the EDT making it safer to use when dealing with Swing, it will also give the EDT and `RepaintManager` some breathing room when scheduling repaints.
- Repaints are controlled by the `RepaintManager` which may consolidate repeated repaint requests into a smaller number of events, which begins to suggest at the cause of your problem.

Let's face it, you only really need to update once a second, to be on the safe side, I might update every half second, but that's me.

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160592/java-gui-clock-using-large-amounts-of-ram/27160772#27160772)